# Remove default 0 from numeric textbox

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

My model has an EditorFor that binds to a not null numeric field in a database.  I wish to keep this field blank so that users can enter or scan numbers into the field.  Unfortunately, it defaults to a 0.  Is there an easy way to remove the 0 while keeping the field not null?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RackNumber, new { id = "RackNumber"})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change model property type to nullable: `public int? RackNumber {get;set;}`

Comment: This is OK, unless you're binding directly to an entity/domain class and not a dto or viewmodel, and the field is not nullable. It's better to use a format string on the field, like so: [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the Value attribute like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RackNumber, new { Value = Model.RackNumber == 0 ? "" : Model.RackNumber.ToString(), id = "RackNumber"})
```

Comment: I get a 'The name 'model' does not exist in the current context' error.

Comment: I updated the answer. Make sure "Model" after the value attribute is title case.